# CSS is limiting the width of the site

Tags: html, css, user-interface, layout

I'm trying to create a clean, cross browser admin template. I have coded up a sidebar nav and then a main content area. I'm running into problems however, because it seems like my content in the main area (white) isn't extending all the way across.

**Code:** http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/Ct5jx/5/

**Preview:** http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/Ct5jx/5/embedded/result/

The table should be taking up the full width of the white content area. How can I remedy this without breaking the layout?

This is the code which might be causing the issue:

```
#framecontent {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #34495E;
}
#maincontent {
    position: fixed;
    left: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using absolute and fixed positioning I would use the following set up (should work in all browser from ie8 up):

**html**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
        left stuff
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        right stuff
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
html, body {height: 100%; max-height: 100%; padding:0; margin:0;}
.wrapper {display:table; width:100%; height:100%;}
.wrapper > div {display:table-cell;}
.wrapper .left {width:200px; background-color:#34495E}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tcgJ6/)

you can add a `min-width` to the `.wrapper` so the right column doesn't shrink below the size you want

[If you need it to work with ie 7, try this](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/tcgJ6/1/)

Comment: Can I ask what the compatibility is of this? Would it be IE8+? Thank you for the help, by the way

Comment: yeah, first one should work in ie8 plus, second one should be ie7 plus

Comment: Assuming IE8+ if fine, do you recommend the first solution as a cleaner, more flexible solution, or in-fact is your second solution better?

Comment: I would probably go with the first as it gives you the flexibility of tables, also if you need to add a right column it is a lot easier and you don't need to worry about clearing floats so there's less markup / css, although having said that it would be easier to add overflow scroll to the second one as with the first you would need to add another div inside the cell with width and height 100% overflow scroll where as the second one you could just add overflow scroll to the .left and .right divs

Comment: @Jimmy if you want to use your original code you can use this: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/Ct5jx/9/